# Cosmological theories assuming initial singular events vs theories assuming perpetual monotonous progression?

Tags: cosmology

I would like to gather opinions on the question: "what are the merits and downfalls of cosmological theories, which assume initial singular events vs theories assuming perpetual monotonous progression?"

Answer (score 0):

Both of these kind of "theories" involve conjectures about how Quantum Gravity is going to be resolved. To get any complete or partial resolution of Quantum Gravity some conjecture will have to make a prediction that can be confirmed by some kind of observation. It is a possibility that no such a conjecture will ever be confirmed by observing a prediction, but there is also a possibility that someday such a confirmed conjecture will be found.